# CalendarExtender Date Validation in a C# project

Tags: c#, validation, date, repeater, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have the following code to create a table using **ASP Repeater Control**:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Reptr" OnItemDataBound="Reptr_ItemDataBound" runat="server" Visible="False">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Start Date
                </td>
                <td>
                    End Date
                </td>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Start" Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("StartDate")).ToShortDateString() %>' ReadOnly="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <act:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarStart" PopupButtonID="DatePickerStart" TargetControlID="Start" onDateSelectionChanged = "checkDate" runat="server"><act:CalendarExtender>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="DatePickerStart" ImageUrl="~/Images/calendar.gif" runat="server" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="End" Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("EndDate")).ToShortDateString() %>' ReadOnly="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <act:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarEnd" PopupButtonID="DatePickerEnd" TargetControlID="End" onDateSelectionChanged = "checkDate" runat="server"></act:CalendarExtender>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="DatePickerEnd" ImageUrl="~/Images/calendar.gif" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Start" Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("StartDate")).ToShortDateString() %>' ReadOnly="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <act:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarStart" PopupButtonID="DatePickerStart" TargetControlID="Start" onDateSelectionChanged = "checkDate" runat="server"><act:CalendarExtender>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="DatePickerStart" ImageUrl="~/Images/calendar.gif" runat="server" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="End" Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("EndDate")).ToShortDateString() %>' ReadOnly="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <act:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarEnd" PopupButtonID="DatePickerEnd" TargetControlID="End" onDateSelectionChanged = "checkDate" runat="server"></act:CalendarExtender>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="DatePickerEnd" ImageUrl="~/Images/calendar.gif" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

For a quick reference, here is how the above code will output to as shown in the below image:

[image: RepeaterTable]

This sequence will have more than two rows for **Start** and **End** date. The number of rows are not fixed and can vary upon selection of a few other things (i.e. they are dynamically loaded in the table of repeater control). The data in these cells is populated by **DataBinding** from the **DataSource**.

Also, the Dates in the table will be populated when it is displayed. The validations happen only on changing any of the dates.

I was trying to incorporate following **validations** on the change of date from the **CalendarExtender**:

- End Date should be **greater** than Start Date
- **Past dates** should not be allowed
- End Date of **current row** should be **less** then the start date of **next row**

I validated for past dates with the following code in my **aspx** page:

```
function checkDate(sender, args) {

        if (sender._selectedDate < new Date()) {
            alert("You cannot select a day earlier than today!");
            sender._selectedDate = new Date();
            sender._textbox.set_Value(sender._selectedDate.format(sender._format));
        }
    }
```

However I cannot call multiple functions from `onSelectedDateChanged()`. I have the following queries:

1. How do I ensure that all the validations mentioned above are performed when the user selects a date from **CalendarExtender** ?
2. How do I store the Dates populated on the repeater table in a **ViewState**?

Comment: What prevents you from checking a date inside date changed callback?